# Unable to read an existing file - No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop

each time I use -put command to copy a local file to hdfs

```
$ hadoop fs -put file:///root/t1/t11 hdfs:///user/amit
```

it gives me the following error

> put: '/root/t1/t11': No such file or directory

I am sure the file exists.
I changed the permissions but still not going through

Please help me

Comment: Whats does `ls -l /root/t1/t11` results?

Comment: [*-rwxrwxrwx 1 hdfs root 87 Apr  8 08:18 /root/t1/t11**]

Comment: Do `chown` as updated in my answer and then try `hadoop fs` commands.

Comment: Whatever your problem is, **chmod 777 is wrong and dangerous**.  Before you proceed, tweak down the permissions of the file to something like 644.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `put` command from different folder other than `/root`. Do this in terminal (as hadoop user):

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/test
sudo cp /root/t1/t11 /usr/local/test/t11
sudo chown hadoop:hadoop /usr/local/test/t11
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/amit
hadoop fs -put /usr/local/test/t11 /user/amit/t11
```

In `sudo chown hadoop:hadoop /usr/local/test/t11`, hadoop:hadoop is your `hadoop user name` and `hadoop group name` respectively.

Comment: Whats is the result for `ls -l /root/t1/t11`?

Comment: Do this: `sudo chown hadoopuser:hadoopgroup /usr/local/test/t11`. (Change hadoopuser and hadoopgroup to your settings) Now, try the `hadoop fs` commands.

Comment: can you please tell me how to find out the list of users and groups?

Comment: The user you are trying to run hadoop commands is your `hadoop username`. Most users including me have configured the group as `hadoop`, so your hadoop group must be `hadoop`. If you want to list all users and groups, try this commands: `compgen -u` for all users and `compgen -g` for all groups.

Answer (score 1):

hope these helps:

$ hadoop fs -put localhost:///root/t1/t11 hdfs:///user/amit

or

$ hadoop fs -put /root/t1/t11 hdfs:///user/amit

or

$ hadoop fs -put /root/t1/t11 hdfs://your_hadoop_host_name/user/amit

in my case all these works.

and test using hadoop user which you have created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal` command. See how to do it: 
1. Creating input folder in DFS:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /input
```

2. Copy the directory from local disk to the newly created 'input' directory in HDFS:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /usr/local/test/t11 /input
```

Comment: I followed your advice and I have tried it before as well. It gives the same error for put, cp, copyFromLocal and similar commands. Below is the current error                                                                                bash-4.1$ hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /root/t1/t11 /input
copyFromLocal: `/root/t1/t11': No such file or directory

Comment: Try to give path without first "/": root/t1/t11 and input.

Comment: Try to get names of all folders i root directory using command with "/" at the end: hdfs dfs -ls /

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are copying the files from `root` user linux home directory ('/root') to `amit` user's hdfs home directory (`/user/amit`) as `hadoop` user. So, one thing to keep in mind is that root user's home directory is not readable to other users.

To make this to work you need to have to copy the file to linux `/tmp` folder (which is universally readable) as the `hadoop` user cannot read the file from root user's home directory in linux file system (this required you to have `sudo` access):

```
sudo cp /root/t1/t11 /tmp
hadoop fs -put /tmp/t11 /user/amit
```

Answer (score 0):

The following combination of commands worked.

```
[root@amit ~]# mkdir /testing
[root@amit ~]# cp /root/t1/t11 /testing
[root@amit ~]# sudo chown hdfs:hadoop /testing
[root@amit ~]# sudo chown hdfs:hadoop /testing/t11
[root@amit ~]# sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -put /testing/t11 hdfs:///user/amit
```

hdfs is my hadoop username

hadoop is my hadoop groupname

I cannot vote up yet as I am new but thank you for the support.